# Flutter Listview builder show data in two rows depending upon `index` is odd or event

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fairly new in Flutter, I am fetching data from api and displaying it in a listview. I have following demo code.

```
/*Other codes*/
return ListView.builder(
          //Other Codes
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: item.length,
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              
      
});
```

My requirement is to show data in Two Rows, such that if the item in  `index` is even show it in first row and if its odd, show it in another row? More like in the Image below.

[image]

***Update:*** There could be many items and can be scrolled horizontally to reveal more items.

Can we achieve this without manipulating the data received from  API? From API the data comes in date-wise sorted in descending order.

Thanks

Comment: Do you always just have 4 items ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy There could be many. scrollable horizontally to reveal more items

Comment: Oh, it's horizontal. Makes sense.

Comment: Have added an answer. Try if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GridView.builder` is probably what you are looking for.

Just give it `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` to make it horizontal.
Then give it `gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2)` to make sure you have only 2 rows.

Then use `SizedBox` to restrict the height of the `GridView` to `90 + 90`.

Finally, use the `childAspectRatio` property of the `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount` to specify that you want your aspect ratio to be `90 / 256`.

```
Color randomColor() => Color.fromARGB(255, Random().nextInt(255), Random().nextInt(100), Random().nextInt(200));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    List<String> array = ["0", "1", "2", "3"];
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Example')),
                body: SizedBox(
                    height: 90 + 90,
                    child: GridView.builder(
                        itemCount: 4,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            childAspectRatio: 90 / 256,
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                        ),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Container(
                                color: randomColor(), child: Text(array[index])
                            );
                        }
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: This seems to work well, I will accept  the answer once I check, thank you so much

Comment: Sure. Will wait. Tell me if something needs to be twaked :D

Comment: @WatsMyName. Did it work ? Would love to know.

Comment: It works, but I am having difficult time setting the height and width of grid items. I want each grid to have width = 265 and height=  90. `childAspectRatio` property doesn't seem to work

Comment: @WatsMyName You can achieve this easily using a `SizedBox`. Have updated my answer. Check it out. You can copy paste that code and run it to check.